# SketchUp: Weird regions in sketch

Tags: 3d-modeling, 3d, sketchup

I'm using SketchUp 8.0.15158.

My sketch has weird regions/lines in it that I can't explain or get rid of. I've redrawn almost the whole thing and the lines persist! See here, highlighted in yellow:

[image]

These dotted lines only show up when I triple-click the back face to select the whole object. Here's what the sketch looks like without selections:

[image]

What are these lines and how can I get rid of them? They are causing weird issues that I can't seem to get around.

Comment: Note: I was able to delete these mystery lines by selecting everything and then de-selecting everything except those dashed lines, and then hitting delete. But I'd still like to know what caused them and what they are.